Is there a way to know what entities got combined in RoomPlan's StructureBuilder final structure?
I'm working with RoomPlan to scan individual rooms and then merging them into a MultiRoom structure using StructureBuilder. After the merge, I end up with a combined structure where the walls from the original rooms have been merged into new walls with new IDs.
I receive a .plist file containing the final structure entities, including walls, floors, etc., each with their respective IDs. However, the new walls created by merging common walls from different rooms are assigned new IDs.
I would like to determine which original walls (from which IDs) were merged into each new wall in the final structure. Specifically, I need to map the original wall IDs to the new wall IDs created during the merging process.
Is there a way to track or identify which original walls have been combined into each new wall? If so, could you provide guidance or examples on how to achieve this?
Thank you!
I have tried the following steps:
Scanning Individual Rooms: I scanned individual rooms using RoomPlan and generated separate .plist files for each room, which include details about walls, floors, and other entities.
Merging Rooms: I used StructureBuilder to merge these individual room scans into a MultiRoom structure. This process combines the walls and other entities from each room into a unified structure.
Analyzing the Output: After merging, I analyzed the resulting .plist file, which contains the new combined structure with updated entity IDs.
I expected to find a way to trace back the new walls in the merged structure to the original walls from the individual scans. Specifically, I hoped to identify how original walls (from their respective room scans) were combined into new walls in the final structure and map these relationships.
Despite this, I am unable to determine which original walls were merged to form each new wall, as the new walls are assigned new IDs and the .plist file does not seem to provide this mapping information directly.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be possible, not in my experience at least. This presents some challenges when trying to figure out a room's walls.
